# I need to recover my files in ubuntu virtual machine after the SSD crash. Only recent vmdk files available. How to recover VM?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, vmdk

I was using tex studio in Ubuntu in a virtual machine. But my SSD crashed and only last 31 .vmdk files as a backup are left as shown in the image. I was writing my PhD thesis in Texstudio, which I want to recover. [.vmdk files screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWQ1T.png)

When I open these .vmdk files in VMWare, I get an error, 'Error while opening the virtual machine: VMX file is corrupt.' Further, I made a new virtual machine and tried to add .vmdk file as the hard drive of the new virtual machine. But it gives the error, 'The file specified is not a virtual disk.' Help!